# update a figure made with imshow(), contour() and quiver()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to know whether one can update a contour done with `contour()`, a vector field done with `quiver()`, and an image done with `imshow()`, without actually having to call those functions again or creating a new figure, axes etc. In other words, is it possible (and is it usually what people do) to update those elements of a figure without re-calling the routines.

I've tried solutions based on `set_array()` and `pyplot.draw()` but I can't make it work for the vector field and contour plot.

Answer (score 6):

Well, you can do this for `imshow` by calling `.set_data()` on the image, then `fig.canvas.draw()` on the figure. I don't see any real performance advantage over just calling `draw()` - both give me about 25FPS with the benchmark below (using `WXAgg` as a backend).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp
import time

def animate_data(data):

    fig,ax = pp.subplots(1,1)

    # I'm not convinced that animated=True does anything either...
    image = ax.imshow(data[0,:,:],animated=True)

    # pp.draw()
    fig.canvas.draw()

    start = time.time()
    tic = start
    for ii in xrange(1,data.shape[0]):
        if not(ii % 10):
            toc = time.time()
            print "FPS =\t%.6G" %(10./(toc-tic))
            tic = time.time()
        image.set_data(data[ii,:,:])

        # pp.draw()
        fig.canvas.draw()

    print "Average FPS =\t%.6G" %(data.shape[0]/(time.time()-start))

fakedata = np.random.randn(200,512,512)
animate_data(fakedata)
```

In the case of `quiver`, you can use `.set_UVC()` to update the plot:

```
fig,ax = subplots(1,1)

u1 = np.random.rand(10,10)
v1 = np.random.rand(10,10)
c1 = np.random.rand(10,10)

q = ax.quiver(u1,v1,c1)
fig.canvas.draw()

u2 = np.random.rand(10,10)
v2 = np.random.rand(10,10)
c2 = np.random.rand(10,10)

q.set_UVC(u2,v2,c2)
fig.canvas.draw()
```

As far as I can tell, you can't update `contour` plots in the same way. I'm not sure there would be all that much to gain anyway, since any solution would still require re-computing where the contour lines should go for a given array input. If I were you I would just call `ax.contour()` and `fig.canvas.draw()`.