# Is it possible to update quiver position coordinates in an animation?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I'd like to draw and animate some particles with matplotlib. Each point has a position and velocity. I am able to draw single frames using matplotlib `quiver`.

But how can I update the quiver data for each frame? (I am using the matplotlib animation class.) I read about the (undocumented?) `quiver.set_UVC()`, but that seems to update only the direction, not position. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015427/update-a-figure-made-with-imshow-contour-and-quiver/12253893#12253893)

Comment: Not duplicate, @ali_m, as set_UVC() does not allow you to update positions, which is what I was asking about.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this via the `Collections` level method `set_offsets`  [(doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.Collection.set_offsets).

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(linspace(0, 100), linspace(0, 100))
q = plt.quiver(X, Y , rand(100, 100), rand(100, 100))
plt.draw()
plt.pause(2)
q.set_offsets(q.get_offsets() * np.array([1, .5]))
plt.draw()
```