# Previous frames not cleared when saving animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I am making a matplotlib animation in which a quiver arrow moves across the page.  This cannot be achieved in the usual way (creating one Quiver object and updating it with each frame of the animation) because although there is a `set_UVC` method for updating the *u, v components*, there is no equivalent method for changing the *x, y position* of the arrows.  Therefore, I am creating a new Quiver object for each frame.

This works fine when I do a `plt.show()` and the animation is drawn on the screen.  The arrow moves from left to right across the page, and when one arrow appears the previous one disappears, which is what I want.  However, when I save as a gif or mp4 the previous arrows are not cleared, so I end up with a whole line of arrows appearing.  How can I fix this?

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation

n = 21
x = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, num=n)
def animate(i):
    q = plt.quiver(x[i:i+1], [0], [1], [0])
    return q,

plt.gca().set_xlim([-1, 1])
anim = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, frames=n,
                                          repeat=True, blit=True)

plt.show()
#anim.save('anim.gif', dpi=80, writer='imagemagick')
#anim.save('anim.mp4', dpi=80, writer='ffmpeg')
```

Comment: is it possible your settings are for transparent figure patches? You can check via `matplotlib.rcParams['savefig.frameon']`, which should be `True` to make each new patch have a solid background (http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) or set the argument using `anim.save('anim.mp4', [..etc..], extra_args={'frameon':True})` (http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html)

Comment: Check this to change the position of the arrows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758942/is-it-possible-to-update-matplotlib-quiver-position-coordinates-in-an-animation

Comment: Using q.set_offsets as suggested by @Jean works perfectly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758942/is-it-possible-to-update-matplotlib-quiver-position-coordinates-in-an-animation), as suggested by Jean-Sébastien above.  My code now reads:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation

n = 21
x = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, num=n)
q = plt.quiver(x[:1], [0], [1], [0])
def animate(i):
    q.set_offsets([[x[i], 0]])
    return q,

plt.gca().set_xlim([-1, 1])
anim = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, frames=n,
                                          repeat=True, blit=True)

plt.show()
#anim.save('anim.gif', dpi=80, writer='imagemagick')
#anim.save('anim.mp4', dpi=80, writer='ffmpeg')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the frame every time in your `animate` function. The code below worked well to me.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation

n = 21
x = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, num=n)

fig = plt.figure()
def animate(i):
    fig.clear() # clear fig
    q = plt.quiver(x[i:i+1], [0], [1], [0])
    plt.gca().set_xlim([-1, 1])
    return q,


anim = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, frames=n,
                                          repeat=True, blit=True)
# plt.show()
# anim.save('anim.gif', dpi=80, writer='imagemagick')
anim.save('anim.mp4', dpi=80, writer='ffmpeg')
```